# FXAA without shaders?

Tags: image-processing, language-agnostic, shader, antialiasing

I'm working on some software that's supposed to be able to capture single images from a connected camera, essentially using a webcam like a photo camera.  I've got that part working, but the images that come out look very "jaggy" and in serious need of antialiasing.

After a bit of research, it seems that the FXAA algorithm is a good choice: it works on an entire image by finding sharp edges and smoothing them, and [its source is freely available on GitHub.](https://gist.github.com/bkaradzic/6011431)  The problem is, it's written entirely in shader code, and I'm capturing images, not rendering them.

Are there any pure software ports of FXAA around that work entirely on a bitmap in main memory, without using shaders?  Googling for stuff like "FXAA C port" and "FXAA Python port" turns up nothing useful, but I can't be the first person who's ever thought of using this without a renderer, right?

Comment: "*I can't be the first person who's ever thought of using this without a renderer, right?*" Why not? Generally speaking, if you're willing to do something like FXAA on the CPU, performance is not the most important issue (especially if Python is acceptable). And there are *far* superior mechanisms for enhancing a video image than FXAA. Indeed, FXAA is used on GPUs because it's an algorithm that offers halfway-decent results and is amenable to high-performance GPU operation. People who want CPU algorithms that offer good image quality don't use FXAA.